# SQlyog to import only new record

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have a Pervasive SQL Database that uses ODBC to connect with.

I can run a scheduler for every 1 hr with import external data tool using ODBC to MySQL but it imports all of the records every time i want instead just importing the rows changed. Any one have any idea on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a where clause on the column. The where clause option can be found in the import external data wizard.